# HtmlAgilityPack in C# showing "A first chance exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll"

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have downloaded the following page using wget and saved it in f.html

http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=gruen&_in_kw=1&_ex_kw=sara+quartz+embassy+bob+robert+elephants+adidas&_sacat=See-All-Categories&_okw=gruen&_oexkw=sara+quartz+embassy+bob+robert+elephants+adidas&_adv=1&_udlo=&_udhi=&_LH_Time=1&_ftrt=903&_ftrv=24&_sabdlo=&_sabdhi=&_samilow=&_samihi=&_sadis=200&_fpos=Zip+code&_fsct=&LH_SALE_CURRENCY=0&_sop=12&_dmd=1&_ipg=50

Now I want to load this page for parsing using HtmlAgilityPack in C#. Using this code snippet

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document = webGet.Load("f.html");
```

Second line is throwing this error

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll
```

What's the solution ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the compiler at hand but I suppose that `"f.html"` is not a well formed Uri. It lacks the schema and the domain.

The correct uri should be like `"http://the.domain.name/f.html"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var url = "http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=gruen&_in_kw=1&_ex_kw=sara+quartz+embassy+bob+robert+elephants+adidas&_sacat=See-All-Categories&_okw=gruen&_oexkw=sara+quartz+embassy+bob+robert+elephants+adidas&_adv=1&_udlo=&_udhi=&_LH_Time=1&_ftrt=903&_ftrv=24&_sabdlo=&_sabdhi=&_samilow=&_samihi=&_sadis=200&_fpos=Zip+code&_fsct=&LH_SALE_CURRENCY=0&_sop=12&_dmd=1&_ipg=50";
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString(url));
```

If you want to load it from a local file then try:

```
var file = "f.html";
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllText(file));
```

Comment: Updated it to include how to load a local file.